# CSS Hover Animation Not Working / Hover Does Not Work

Tags: html, css

My CSS Hover is not working properly.
I was trying to make a transition & animation for a button when you hover but it does not work.
My code :

```css
button.btn__1{
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 39px;
  margin: 7px;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  background-color: rgba(95, 95, 95, 0.836);
  color: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  opacity: 1;
  
}
button.btn__1:hover {
  opacity: 4;
  translate: scaleY(-8px);
}
```

```html
<center><button class="btn__1"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/cable-release.png"/>Invite</button></center>
```

Please help me!
Sorry if there is any grammar mistakes.

Comment: `<center>` is an obsolete element and should no longer be used.

Comment: Is there any alternatives for <center>? Or do we use , text-align : center; with CSS for the replacement of <center>?

Answer (score 2):

`translate` and `scale` are properties to `transform`. Also, `opacity` ranges between 0-1, and you got `opacity: 4` on `:hover`. I presume you want to translate (move) and change opacity to 0.4, otherwise you need to explain better what you want to achieve.

```css
button.btn__1{
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 39px;
  margin: 7px;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  background-color: rgba(95, 95, 95, 0.836);
  color: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  opacity: 1;
  
}
button.btn__1:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: translateY(-8px);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn__1"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/cable-release.png"/>Invite</button>
```

Comment: This helped me so much! This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I change your code a little from:

```
translate: scaleY(-8px);
```

to:

```
transform: scaleY(0.8);
```

and it does work. I suggest you to read [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleY()).

```css
button.btn__1{
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 39px;
  margin: 7px;
  padding: 20px 35px;
  background-color: rgba(95, 95, 95, 0.836);
  color: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: 0.1s;
  opacity: 1;
  
}
button.btn__1:hover {
  opacity: 4;
  transform: scaleY(0.8);
}
```

```html
<center><button class="btn__1"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/metro/26/000000/cable-release.png"/>Invite</button></center>
```